# OrientDB 3 HTTP Rest API - Cannot find a command requester for type: gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I'm using OrientDB 3, and I'd like to execute a series of gremlin queries outside of Gremlin Conosle. Specifically, I'd like to run Gremlin Recipe for Degree Centrality.
[http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#degree-centrality/](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#degree-centrality)

To achieve my goal, I'm trying to use Batch command from OrientDB 3 RESTful API. However, I receive this error whenever I set language to gremlin:

**"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a command requester for type: gremlin"**

[postman - body and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGu3I.png)

Is there any config file that should be modified in order to use Gremlin in HTTP API?

Answer (score 0):

There're two things here:

1. You'll have to make sure you have downloaded "**OrientDB with Gremlin Server**" and not just the default OrientDB server for your OS.
2. You can use the endpoint

> POST: https://{hostname}:{port}/command/{database_name}/gremlin

with POST body being your gremlin command like:

> g.V().group().by().by(bothE().count())

Comment: I've installed OrientDB with Tinkerpop 3.x. I'm trying to use BATCH: https://localhost:2480/batch/demodb, but I get this error when I use Gremlin. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGu3I.png